# how to build libfranka on Windows 11

Tags: visual-studio, poco-libraries, vcpkg

Please advise me on the following issue.

I am trying to build libfranka on Window 11 as explained here: https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/installation_windows.html. I could install eigen3 and poco packages through vcpkg. However, when I try to open the CMakeLists with Visual Studio, I receive the following error.
Could NOT find Poco (missing: Poco_INCLUDE_DIR Poco_LIBRARIES Net  Foundation)!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on windows 10 using both VS 2017 & VS 2019. I think I fixed that error on VS 2019 using "vcpkg integrate install", https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html. However, this has just given me an new error of "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory" which I have not yet been able to fix.